# Flutter web apps containing tracker from UNPKG

Tags: flutter

I have just build a flutter web app - when running it in a safari browser I can see it has blocked one tracker [UNPKG](https://unpkg.com)

Do you know why? I have not added any tracker my self. To recreate this, just create a standard flutter app: flutter create and build it to release for web.

Could it be some local to the app itself, loading some content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter downloads some fonts and CanvasKit on launch. It's the same reason sometimes you'll load the app and nothing will show until you refresh and the same reason Amazon's logo seems to vanish. The difference being Amazon is hosting their own stuff and if you're like me you don't want to rely on everyone and their brother to print hello world. The solution's here if you haven't already googled it: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70101